# Wordpress how to make sticky navigation menu / make the menu stick to the top all the time?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, sticky

I am using Wordpress default theme Twenty Twelve, my website is: http://ninarakovec.com.

I would like to make my existing navigation menu stick to the top all the time whilst scrolling, for example like website called wpsites (can't post the link because of stackoverflow's link limit).

You can view the theme's CSS here: http://pastebin.com/muXyT6AY

How would I go on about doing this, I have no idea what to do, I currently have made it so you can click on the navigation bar and it takes you to that respective section on the page, but the menu doesn't stick to the top so it isn't what I wanted. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! But how could I get rid of this area? http://i.imgur.com/MQotFAN.jpg

Comment: kill the margin-top on .site-navigation

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find .site-navigation in my CSS file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Then add .site-navigation{margin-top: 0;} to your css.

Comment: Yeah I tried that before but it didn't work, am I supposed to do anything else other than adding that to my css?

Comment: have you tried #site-navigation{margin-top: 0 !important;} ??

Comment: sry my fault #site-navigation was an id not a class

Comment: Thanks so much! You've helped me so much, I appreciate all your help, it's working as intended now! You rock dude!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the `.site-header` class into this:

```
.site-header {
        padding: 24px 0;
        padding: 1.714285714rem 0;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but the problem is that it is not always shown, for example, now if you scroll down the menu can be hidden behind the slider and text, how do I make this act "always on top" so it can always be seen?

Comment: Add a `z-index: 1;` to the `.site-header` css.

Comment: Ok that achieved the effect I wanted, however, it still looks derpy, now I want to get rid of those white areas that are on top and bottom; http://i.imgur.com/tstcfee.jpg